# LocationManager: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm new in this community but I already used to learn much from you! Actually I started programming on Android Studio but now I stuck somewhere. I'm sure it's something simple you will find out quick.

In the Emulator Nexus 5 API 23 (the one already installed in Android Studio) it's working but on my mobile Android 5.1.1 API 22 it doensnt start.

**Error**:
`09-20 19:15:11.526  17776-17776/com.example.stefano.aiutomamma01 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.stefano.aiutomamma01, PID: 17776
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method checkSelfPermission(Ljava/lang/String;)I in class Lcom/example/stefano/aiutomamma01/MainActivity; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.example.stefano.aiutomamma01.MainActivity' appears in /data/app/com.example.stefano.aiutomamma01-2/base.apk)
            at com.example.stefano.aiutomamma01.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2332)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2442)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1351)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5373)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1020)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:815)`

JAVA Code:

```
package com.example.stefano.aiutomamma01;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener {

    //GPS
    private LocationManager locationManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //GPS
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        //CATCHED
        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    public void requestPermissions(@NonNull String[] permissions, int requestCode)
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for Activity#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    //GPS
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        String str = "Latitude: " + location.getLatitude() + "Longitude: " + location.getLongitude();

        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    //GPS
    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    //GPS
    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    //GPS
    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }

}
```

Sorry for the bad post. Btw: I couldnt find solution in the web...

Greetings

Comment: Runtime permissions were introduced in API 23 same as the methods which are used for their handling. Use the [`ActivityCompat`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat.html) class methods to handle this in backwards compatible fashion.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Runtime permissions were introduced in API 23 same as the methods which are used for their handling. Use the [`ActivityCompat`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat.html) class methods to handle this in backwards compatible fashion.

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    ...
}
```

And so on.

Comment: Thank you! Now its working. But the application isnt checking the location as in Google maps. Do you know why?

Comment: Do you have GPS turned on? Are you outside? The code seems ok.

Comment: i'm inside. But with Google Maps its work. I guess it is not checking for the location. Ill try it outside.

Comment: When I go in the settings then Location. There I cannot see my app. I just see Google Maps, Google Play and Facebook. Maybe I have to add it there...

Comment: On Lollipop and below it should work now. On Marshamllow you actually have to request the permissions when checkSelfPermission returns false. I suggest you read this carefully https://developer.android.com/preview/features/runtime-permissions.html

Comment: @EugenPechanec Do I need android support v7 to use ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission ?

Comment: @AlexanderFragotsis No, support-v4 is enough.

Comment: @EugenPechanec Thanks! I couldn't see the checkSelfPermission method because my v4 file was outdated

Comment: @AlexanderFragotsis Good point. It has to be at least release 23.x.x because `Activity.checkSelfPermission` was introduced in API 23.